# What's the ideal way to pass temporary, non-copyable and mutable arguments in C++?

Tags: c++

For `const` parameters I can simply use `const T&`, but for mutable arguments, such code won't compile:

```
TileMap load_map(std::istream &);
auto map = load_map(std::ifstream(save_file_path));
```

The parameter of `load_map` has to be a mutable reference, but only a `const` reference can be bound to a temporary. In order to avoid the temporary polluting the whole scope, I'm currently writing code like this:

```
TileMap load_map(std::istream &);
auto map = [&save_file_path]() {
    auto save_file = std::ifstream(save_file_path);
    return load_tilemap(save_file);
}();
```

Is there any more concise and ergonomic way for this?

Comment: Do you know what rvalue references are, how they work, and how to use them?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yes, but rvalue references can't be bound to normal lvalue variables. Or do I have to write lvalue and rvalue version overloads for every such functions? That would seem more verbose than simply use lambdas.

Comment: An rvalue reference will be the answer for the shown code that's included in the question. If you have other consideration to work with such as multiple "overloads for every such functions", that also needs to be included in the question. We're not mind readers.

Comment: no need to use a lambda to limit scope, plain old braces will do the job. Needing to take a mutable reference to a temporary is quite a strange requirement (which is why the language prevents it), any chance of a [mre]?

Comment: @AlanBirtles To use a lambda has the advantage that initialized variable could be const. I believe braces would require creating the variable first and mutating it, right? As for the reason for such requirement, I was experimenting with copy ellision when writing this function. I thought I can write "TileMap load_map(std::istream)" and have the compiler figure it out automatically, but apparently not. So I wonder whether this behaviour (mutable lvalue & to temporary) can be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting aside that it is a very strange requirement to want to bind an lvalue-reference to a temporary (which does not make sense to me), you could still overload your function with an rvalue reference parameter and forward the call.

Assuming your:

```
TileMap load_map(std::istream &);
```

You could define:

```
TileMap load_map(std::istream && istr) // accepts an rvalue-reference
{
   return load_map(istr); // Will call the lvalue-reference version (since istr is an lvalue inside the function)
}
```

From now, your call would work on its own:

```
auto map = load_map(std::ifstream(save_file_path));
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answer gives you the syntax you asked for, but I think what you're currently doing is the right way to write this, though you may want to make `map` a function instead of a lambda if it's called often.

`load_map` takes an lvalue reference because it wants an already-open stream.  Opening and closing the stream are not its problem.  That means its the caller's job to control the lifetime of the stream.  If you did this with a containing scope, like in your lambda, it's all very clear.

If, however, you wrote something like:

```
my_map = load_map( static_cast<std::istream&>( std::ifstream(save_file_path) ) );
```

(the other answer is a slicker syntax for doing the same thing), it will probably work in this case, but you don't have a containing scope - you're relying on the lifetime of a temporary to manage your file stream.  It should work in this particular case, but I think it's anything but clear.

I think you're just trying to cut a corner to write this in one line.  If you want some syntactic sugar, your current lambda (or perhaps a similar function that takes a file as a parameter) is much clearer than using temporaries and casting tricks.

Comment: Using a "cast" function, as inspired by `std::move`, one could have a helper `template <typename T> T& temp(T&& x) { return x; }` and then do `foo(temp(std::istringstream("Hello world"));`.  The `temp` "cast" would show intent, rather than by accident.

Comment: @Eljay Thanks, that seems a nice solution. Though I'm still thinking whether it's possible for the compiler to analyze and do this automatically. I mean, if it's smart enough to elide a lot moves and copies (I was experimenting with copy elision when I wrote the code in the question), it would seem to be capable of this, too.

Comment: @RevolverOcelot • that behavior is explicitly prohibited in the language because it would be too easy to create unintentional silent bugs that the compiler could not flag.  Intentional implicit behavior looks the same to the compiler as unintentional implicit behavior.